# Is there a way to compare strings between different arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm currently working on a data visualisation tool that visualises international trade data. I have the trade data in one csv which I put in array nested_data with d3.js, however some of the commodity names are too long and are shortened by '...', like this:

```
Afghanistan,"2012","2 Grondstoffen niet eetbaar behalve...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
```

In another array (SITCArray) I have both the shortened name and the full name as follows:

```
let SITCArray = [
{
"A018540": {
   "Title": "2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve...",
   "Description": "2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve brandstoffen"
},
```

What I would like to do is loop through both arrays and if SITCArray.Title matches a string in nested_data, replace that string with SITCArray.Description. Is this possible? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the SITCArray, and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the Title and Description. If the Title matches a string in the nested array update that string with the Description.

```js
const nested = ['Afghanistan', '2012', '2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve...', 'Invoerwaarde', 'mln euro', '.'];
const SITCArray = [{'A018540': {'Title': '2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve...', 'Description': '2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve brandstoffen'}}];

const arr = SITCArray.forEach(obj => {
  const key = Object.keys(obj);
  const { Title, Description } = obj[key];
  const index = nested.findIndex(el => el === Title);
  if (index) nested[index] = Description;
});

console.log(nested);
```

Comment: My goal is to update the const nested so that '2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve...' is updated to '2 Grondstoffen, niet eetbaar, behalve brandstoffen'. Your solution logs SITCArray where Title was changed to Description.

Comment: Edited: that should do it. @MartFijten